# C#: conversion of field to month and year format

Tags: c#-4.0

I have the line of code below

```
txtCustomers.Text = _myCustList[0].F5Customer.dateActive;
_myCustList[0].F5Customer.dateActive returns : 2/27/2014 12:00:00AM
```

I want the date format to be in [month , year]

I tried the code below but no luck

```
txtCustomers.Text = _myCustList[0].F5Customer.dateActive.ToString("MMMM , YYYY");
```

How can I get it in the [month, year] format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the "month and year" format exactly? Maybe you want the complete month-name and year, then use lowercase `yyyy`, so `"MMMM , yyyy"` instead of `"MMMM , YYYY"`:

```
txtCustomers.Text = _myCustList[0].F5Customer.dateActive.ToString("MMMM , yyyy");
```

**Edit**: as commented that property is a `string` not a `DateTime`. Why is a property that is called `dateActive` a string in the first place? I would make it a `DateTime` property. Otherwise you always have to parse it to a `DateTime`.

```
txtCustomers.Text = DateTime.Parse(_myCustList[0].F5Customer.dateActive).ToString("MMMM , yyyy");
```

Comment: Yes. Complete Month Name and year. The line of code does not work.

Comment: @user2320476: i have tested it, `DateTime.Now.ToString(MMMM , yyyy)` returns `November , 2014` for me. What means "does not work at all"?

Comment: Method ToString has 0 parameters but invoked with 1 argument is the error message I am getting.

Comment: @user2320476: then i guess that `dateActive` is a nullable datetime or string instead of a `DateTime`, what is it? If it's a `DateTime? ` you can use `dateActive.Value.ToString...` if you are sure that all have a value.

Comment: dateActive is a string

Comment: @user2320476: so why is a property that is called `dateActive` a string in the first place? I would make it a `DateTime` property. Otherwise you always have to parse it to a `DateTime`. Edited my answer accordingly.